# How can you unmount or unjoin a unionfs path?

Tags: linux, unionfs

I was able to set up a unionfs path but realized I wanted to change it. I can't seem to overwrite, unmount, or move the unionfs target directory. Is there a command that a non-root user (who set up the union) to change it?

```
myuser@maven ~ $ unionfs \
   -o cow \
   -o statfs_omit_ro \
   /home/myuser/files/pre-upload:/home/myuser/gd-media=RO \
   /home/myuser/union-media

fuse: mountpoint is not empty fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option

myuser@maven ~ $ umount /home/myuser/union-media
umount: /home/myuser/union-media: Permission denied

myuser@maven ~ $ mv union-media OLD-union-media
mv: cannot move 'union-media' to 'OLD-union-media': Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `fusermount -u mountpoint`. This is the direct command to unmount a FUSE filesystem.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I was also able to also fix it by killing the `unionfs` process from top.